# How to find in a composite key using just one part of the key

Tags: jpa, key, composite

I have my Entity:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "Hoja.findAll", query = "SELECT h FROM Hoja h")
public class Hoja implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private HojaPK id;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to Cuestionario
    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE })
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Cuestionario cuestionario;

    public Hoja() {
    }

}

@Embeddable
public class HojaPK implements Serializable {
    // default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    //Correspond with "id" in Cuestionario 
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;

    private int dia;

    public HojaPK() {
    }
}
```

which will have values like this:

1 0

1 1

1 2

2 0

2 1

2 2

2 3

Well, I would like to make a namedQuery like this:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Hoja.getHojaById", query = "SELECT h FROM Hoja h where h.id = :id")
```

to obtain for id=1,

1 0

1 1

1 2

The problem is Hoja has a composite key and it seems I have to pass two values, one for id and one for dia

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use

```
where h.id.id=1
```

I suggest rename HojaPK property in Hoja class

```
h.hojaPk.id=1
```

Comment: Hi. I get a message: Parameter with that position [1] did not exist; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that position [1] did not exist

Comment: Paste here SQL statement.